Network Switch to Router Connection not working
I have the following network setup:

3rd Floor - ISP Router
1st floor - Network Switch

I want to add a router to extend the WiFi range on the ground floor.
The following connections are working:

Network Switch and the second Router with Short Ethernet cable (1m)
Network Switch and Laptop with long Ethernet cable (10m)

But when I connect the Network Switch to the same second router with the 10m Ethernet cable, it connects for a second and disconnects immediately for 15 seconds. It continues the connect/disconnect cycle. It makes the orange light on router go on and off every 15 seconds.
Can someone help me diagnose and resolve the issue?
Is the second router not getting enough power through the switch when there is a long cable? Is my long cable faulty? But the connectivity works with the laptop seamlessly.

If it works with one cable, and not with another, then the reason is usually that cable is faulty - have you tried a different 10 meter cable? Modern ethernet cables should have no issues out to 100 meters, so the length itself is not a problem unless you're running it around a huge magnet or something. Depending on the router model, you might be able to log in and see a system log where it complains about something more specific

Adding a 2nd router to an existing network is tricky and can cause problems. It sounds like you really want an access point. To better understand what is happening, can you tell us (a) the make/model of the 2nd router and (b) which port (WAN or LAN) you connected to your switch?
If you connected the WAN port, you need to choose the 2nd router's internal IP carefully.  If you used a LAN port, you need to make sure you disable DHCP and other services and assign a specific IP that is compatible with your ISP router.

Thank you @Cpt.Whale, There was issue with the Cable.
I was using D-Link Cat 6 Networking Cable. And cut 3 pieces of 10meter of that cable and crimped them manually. All those 10meter pieces gave the same result.
But it worked when I replaced the cable with FEDUS Cat6 Ethernet Cable(10meter) which was already crimped.
